# How can I approach this number theory logic puzzle more formally?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics, logic, recreational-mathematics

I have a number theory question that I *think* I'm supposed to apply the pigeonhole principle to. I've figured out the correct answer just with logic, but I feel like there is a more formal way to do it that I can actually show my work for.

Ten inhabitants of an island populated by knights, who never lie, and knaves, who always lie, were given ten different numbers between 1 and 10.

- When asked "Is your number divisible by 2?" 3 people said yes
- When asked "Is your number divisible by 4?" 6 people replied yes
- When asked "Is your number divisible by 5?" 2 people replied yes

How many of the ten are knaves and which numbers were given to them?

EDIT: My solution:

The incorrect numbers of people with the numbers in statements 1 and 2 imply that there *are* some amount of knaves. Looking at statement 3, the only way 2 people replied yes is if there are no knaves, 2 knaves, or 4 knaves. Statment 2 implies that there must be, at fewest, 4 knaves (as if the knights had both 4 and 8). Therefore, there are 4 knaves total. Statement 2 shows us that, because there are 4 knaves, they must *not* have 4 and 8 and we know two knaves have 5 and 10 from statement 3. This means that, for statement 1 to be true, the other two knaves must have even numbers, 2 and 6 in this case. Therefore, we know that there are 4 knaves with 2, 5, 6, and 10 and 6 knights with 1, 3, 4, 7, 8, and 9.

Comment: Please edit to include your efforts.  Adding in the solution "by logic" would help.

Comment: @lulu Just did it

Comment: Looking at your solution:  Honestly, I think it has to be close to optimal.  Very short and clear.  I doubt you can do much better.

Comment: The way I did it is that from (1) and (2), we know 2,6,10 are knaves because only those three numbers switched from yes to no and there were three switches from no to yes. For (3), those knaves gave two yes and one no. Therefore all other people said yes to that question, meaning they all told the truth except 5. So 2, 5, 6, 10 are knaves.

Comment: Dang, okay! That's a lot quicker for sure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Less elegant, but more formal, alternative approach:

Let $~A,B,~$ and $~C~$ denote the sets $~\{2,4,6,8,10\}, ~\{4,8\},~$ and $~\{5,10\},~$ respectively.

Let $~L~$ denote the number of liars.

For $~k \in ~\{A,B,C\}~$ let $~T_k,~L_k~$ denote the number of truth-tellers and liars assigned to set $~k,~$ respectively.

Note that someone will answer yes to a divisibility question if and only if **either** :

- They are a truth-teller assigned to the pertinent set.
- They are a liar, not assigned to the pertinent set.

So, from the data:

- $T_A + F_A = 5, ~T_A + (L - F_A) = 3 \implies $ 
  $T_A = 4 - (L/2), ~F_A = 1 + (L/2).$
- $T_B + F_B = 2, ~T_B + (L - F_B) = 6 \implies $ 
  $T_B = 4 - (L/2), ~F_B = -2 + (L/2).$
- $T_C + F_C = 2, ~T_B + (L - F_C) = 2 \implies $ 
  $T_C = 2 - (L/2), ~F_C = (L/2).$

At this point, there are three possibilities, for the value of $T_B$:

- $T_B = 0 \implies L = 8.$
- $T_B = 1 \implies L = 6.$
- $T_B = 2 \implies L = 4.$

The first two possibilities above can be ruled out, because they would each cause more than $2$ Liars to not be assigned to set $C$.  This would yield a contradiction, because only $2$ people said $\color{red}{\text{yes}}$ to the divisibility by $5$ question.

Therefore, you now know that $L = 4$ and two of the $4$ liars were assigned to set $C = \{5,10\}.$

Further, you know that $T_A = T_B = 2.$  This implies that two of the truth-tellers were assigned to set $B = \{4,8\}$ and none of the truth-tellers were assigned to $A \cap (\neg B) = \{2,6,10\}.$

Therefore, since there were only $~4~$ liars, they must have been assigned to $\{5,10\} \cup \{2,6,10\} = \{2,5,6,10\}.$